# Confused by notation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location

Would someone be so kind as to explain what is happening with the statement below. I an a bit puzzeled by `<MKAnnotation>` between id and mp, it not something I have seen before.

```
id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
```

many thanks

gary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
id <MKAnnotation> mp
```

means that mp object is expected to conform to `MKAnnotation` protocol (and I suppose assignments you make to that objects will be checked at compile time whenever possible).

Answer (score 1):

It tells you that the object returned will meet the protocol MKAnnotation

see [Apple's objective-C concepts](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Articles/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-TPXREF151)